# how can I select both label and input?

Tags: jquery, select

I have form containing several options like this:

```
<label for="edit-attributes-2-29" class="option">
    <input type="checkbox"
          class="form-checkbox" value="29" 
          id="edit-attributes-2-29" name="attributes[2][29]">
    Cajunkryddad biffstek, +30 Kr
</label>
```

I need to select the whole surrounding div(not included above). when I use .html() I only get the labels and the text. not the input/checkbox.

Feels like something wrong. The whole thing is created by a php-script, so maybe that's the problem...

Someone got an idea?

Comment: I'm not clear on the selecting bit...you want both the `<label>` and the `<input>`, but you want to actually select a `<div>`?  If you could give a bit more detail (and show the wrapping `<div>` markup) I could say which selector would do the job.

Comment: Hi Nick.
when I select the surrounding <div> using .html(), everything containing is selected except for some reason the inputs.

 <div class="form-checkboxes"><div id="edit-attributes-2-28-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-attributes-2-28" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="28" id="edit-attributes-2-28" name="attributes[2][28]"> Apelsinkryddat kycklingspett, +28 Kr</label>
</div>

</div>

Comment: Add that to the original question!

Comment: No sorry. It was all my fault. I had used a function to remove colons(:) from some other labels and somehow that function did something with the inputs in all labels.

I got the solution now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the markup, the `<label>` should be *beside* the `<input>`, not containing it, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="29" id="edit-attributes-2-29" name="attributes[2][29]">
<label for="edit-attributes-2-29" class="option"> Cajunkryddad biffstek, +30 Kr</label>
```

Comment: Isn't it also valid for the `input` to be contained within the `label`?

Comment: @Eric - It can yes, but when you're *selecting* children (most often the case, not always) you want them as siblings.  Is it valid? Yes, though technically you're not supposed to have the `for` attribute in that case...it's assumed to be for the *single* control element inside (only one can be within).